Mockk how to verify that a method accepting constructor lambda is invoked
Hey there I am having issues with method accepting constructor type of lambda with following signature:
    class EventLog() {
       inline fun log(block: Builder.() -> Unit) = Builder(logger.atInfo()).apply(block).build().log()
    }

My unit test includes the following fragment:
 mockkStatic(::eventLogger)
 every { eventLogger.log (
            any<com.tlx.bundling.common.logging.Logger.Builder.()-> Unit>()
        )} returns Unit

My end goal is to verify that eventLogger.log() {
whatever
}
is invoked at least 1 time.
this code is throwing exception:

Receiver class kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1$Subclass1 does not
define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract
java.lang.Object invoke(java.lang.Object)' of interface
kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1. java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
Receiver class kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1$Subclass1 does not
define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract
java.lang.Object invoke(java.lang.Object)' of interface
kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1.   at
com.tlx.bundling.subscriber.adapters.iqiyi.IQIYIubscriberManagerTest$1$2.invokeSuspend$lambda$0(IQIYIubscriberManagerTest.kt:170)
at
io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator$record$block$1.invoke(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:24)
at
io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator$enhanceWithRethrow$1.invoke(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:76)


You cannot do this. because log is an inline function. How about verifying that the parameterless Logger.log() is called instead (assuming build() returns a Logger)?

I can not mockStatick Logger class. It is a bug in Mockk I believe It throws Stackoverflow in the application.

What If I change the method to not be inline ?

Yeah, then it's theoretically possible. I don't understand why you are using mockStatic though. Wouldn't you want to do mock<EventLog>()? Please provide more context.

eventLogger is a global val eventLogger:EventLog = EventLog(), it is not injected or something around these lines. So my understanding is that it is static.

Okay, so problem solved?

@Sweeper Thanks! Changing the "inline" solved the original question.

Inline functions are inlined. This means that there isn't actually a call when you write eventLogger.log { ... }. Instead, the compiler replaces that call with the body of log - i.e. Builder(logger.atInfo()).apply { ... }.build().log().
So to check for a call to log, you actually need to check every call in  Builder(logger.atInfo()).apply { ... }.build().log(). And you cannot distinguish a call to log from someone literally writing Builder(logger.atInfo()).apply { ... }.build().log() in their code.
Or, you can just remove inline.
